# React has detected a change in the order of Hooks error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, vercel, rerender, use-ref

I tried implementing infinite scroll using **useSWRInfinite** hook.

Found a code from an Youtube tutorial  and made little alteration.

But got an error named **"React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by InfiniteDataList."**

2 hours of debugging -- no solution found.

[Picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2mHs.png)

**Youtube tutorial code** --> https://github.com/gdangelo/micro-blogging-workshop/blob/main/components/InfiniteDataList.js
**Youtube tutorial link** --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FsngdxyvFrQ

**MY CODE:**

**InfiniteDataList.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useInfiniteQuery } from "../../hooks";
import MessageWrapper from "../../UI/MessageWrapper";
import { isInViewport } from "../../Utility/windowUtils";
import { useDebouncedCallback } from "use-debounce";
import DefaultListItemComponent from "./components/DefaultListItemComponent";
import DefaultContainerComponent from "./components/DefaultContainerComponent";
import DefaultLoadMoreComponent from "./components/DefaultLoadMoreComponent";

const InfiniteDataList = ({
  queryKey,
  initialData = [],
  listItemComponent: ListItemComponent = DefaultListItemComponent,
  containerComponent: ContainerComponent = DefaultContainerComponent,
  onError = () => {},
  onEmpty = () => {},
  onEmptyComponent: OnEmptyComponent = null,
  onNoMoreData = () => {},
  noMoreDataComponent: NoMoreDataComponent = null,
  isAutoLoadMoreAtEnd = true,
  autoLoadMoreAtEndOptions: {
    timeout = 500,
    onLoadMoreDetected = () => {},
  } = {},
  loadMoreComponent: LoadMoreComponent = DefaultLoadMoreComponent,
}) => {
  // hooks
  const {
    data,
    error,
    hasNextPage,
    fetchNextPage,
    isFetchingInitialData,
    isFetchingNextPageData,
  } = useInfiniteQuery(queryKey, { initialData });
  const moreRef = useRef();

  const loadMore = useDebouncedCallback(() => {
    if (isInViewport(moreRef.current)) {
      onLoadMoreDetected();
      fetchNextPage();
    }
  }, timeout);
  const getLoadMoreRef = () => moreRef;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAutoLoadMoreAtEnd) {
      window.addEventListener("scroll", loadMore);
    }
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", loadMore);
  }, []);

  // some configuration
  OnEmptyComponent = OnEmptyComponent && (() => <h4>No Details found</h4>);
  NoMoreDataComponent =
    NoMoreDataComponent &&
    (() => <MessageWrapper message="No More Data found !" />);

  // helper utils
  const infiniteQueryProps = {
    data,
    error,
    hasNextPage,
    fetchNextPage,
    isFetchingInitialData,
    isFetchingNextPageData,
  };

  // if error occurs
  if (error) {
    onError(error);
    console.log("error");
  }

  // no data found
  if (!isFetchingInitialData && data?.length === 0) {
    onEmpty();
    console.log(typeof OnEmptyComponent);
    return <OnEmptyComponent />;
  }

  // no more data to load
  if (!hasNextPage) {
    onNoMoreData();
  }

  return (
    <ContainerComponent loading={isFetchingInitialData}>
      {data?.map((item, index) => (
        <ListItemComponent key={index} {...item} />
      ))}
      {hasNextPage ? (
        <LoadMoreComponent
          {...infiniteQueryProps}
          getLoadMoreRef={getLoadMoreRef}
        />
      ) : (
        <NoMoreDataComponent {...infiniteQueryProps} />
      )}
    </ContainerComponent>
  );
};

export default InfiniteDataList;
```

**useInfiniteQuery.js**

```
import useSWRInfinite from "swr/infinite";
import { axiosInstance } from "../Utility/axiosInstance";

function getFetcher(requestType = "get") {
  return (url, dataToPost) =>
    axiosInstance[requestType](url, dataToPost).then((res) => res.data);
}

export function useInfiniteQuery(
  queryKey,
  { initialData, requestType = "get" }
) {
  const { data, error, size, setSize } = useSWRInfinite(
    (pageIndex, previousPageData) => {
      // reached the end
      if (previousPageData && !previousPageData.after) return null;
      // first page
      if (pageIndex === 0) return queryKey;
      // next pages
      const search = queryKey.includes("?");
      return `${queryKey}${search ? "$" : "?"}cursor=${encodeURIComponent(
        JSON.stringify(previousPageData.after)
      )}`;
    },
    getFetcher(requestType),
    initialData
  );

  // to fetch next page from react component
  function fetchNextPage() {
    setSize((prev) => prev + 1);
  }

  // flatten all the data obtained so far to a single array
  const flattenPages = data?.flatMap((page) => page.data) ?? [];

  // indicates whether the api will have data for another page
  const hasNextPage = !!data?.[size - 1]?.after;

  // isLoading for initial request
  const isFetchingInitialData = !data && !error;

  // isLoading for other requests including the initial request
  const isFetchingNextPageData =
    isFetchingInitialData ||
    (size > 0 && data && typeof data[size - 1] === "undefined");

  return {
    data: flattenPages,
    error,
    hasNextPage,
    fetchNextPage,
    isFetchingInitialData,
    isFetchingNextPageData,
  };
}
```

**isInViewport.js**

```
// Check if element is visible inside the viewport
export function isInViewport(element) {
  if (!element) return false;

  const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (
    rect.top >= 0 &&
    rect.left >= 0 &&
    rect.bottom <=
      (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
    rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
  );
}
```

**DefaultLoadMoreComponent.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
const DefaultLoadMoreComponent = ({ getLoadMoreRef = () => {} }) => {
  const ref = getLoadMoreRef();
  return <div ref={ref} />;
};
export default DefaultLoadMoreComponent;
```

**DefaultListItemComponent.js**

```
import React from "react";
const DefaultListItemComponent = ({ children = [] }) => <div>{children}</div>;

export default DefaultListItemComponent;
```

**DefaultContainerComponent.js**

```
import React from "react";
import AsyncDiv from "../../../UI/AsyncDiv";

const DefaultContainerComponent = ({ children = [], ...rest }) => (
  <AsyncDiv {...rest}>{children}</AsyncDiv>
);

export default DefaultContainerComponent;
```

**Component where I render InfiniteDataList component**

```
import React from "react";
import InfiniteDataList from "../../../../../UI/InfiniteDataList";
import PaginatedLeads from "./components/PaginatedLeads";
import { getError } from "../../../../../Utility/apiUtils";

const ViewAllLeads = (props) => {
  return (
    <InfiniteDataList
      initialData={[]}
      listItemComponent={PaginatedLeads}
      onError={(err) =>
        window.flash({ title: getError(err).message, type: "error" })
      }
      queryKey="/employee/leads"
    />
  );
};

export default ViewAllLeads;
```

**PaginatedLeads.js**

```
import React from "react";

const PaginatedLeads = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  return <div>PaginatedLeads</div>;
};

export default PaginatedLeads;
```

Comment: This error usually means that you are using `hooks` in a conditional way and for this reason the order in which they are declared changes based on the conditions. You cannot use hooks this way because React would not be able to detect the previous value of the hook. I haven't found a potential issue like this in you code but you can have a look in other parts of you codebase and see if you are accidentally using some hooks conditionally.

Comment: @AntonioPantano Thanks helping. finally I figured out the problem. Its actually a syntax error. I will answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

It is my mistake.

In **useInfiniteQuery.js** file, I passed the initial data in wrong format.

**Wrong syntax -- see the last before line(initialData)**

```
    const { data, error, size, setSize } = useSWRInfinite(
        (pageIndex, previousPageData) => {
          // reached the end
          if (previousPageData && !previousPageData.after) return null;
          // first page
          if (pageIndex === 0) return queryKey;
          // next pages
          const search = queryKey.includes("?");
          return `${queryKey}${search ? "&" : "?"}cursor=${encodeURIComponent(
            JSON.stringify(previousPageData.after)
          )}`;
        },
        getFetcher(requestType),
        initialData
      );
```

**Right syntax -- see the last before line({ fallbackData: initialData })**

```
      const { data, error, size, setSize } = useSWRInfinite(
        (pageIndex, previousPageData) => {
          // reached the end
          if (previousPageData && !previousPageData.after) return null;
          // first page
          if (pageIndex === 0) return queryKey;
          // next pages
          const search = queryKey.includes("?");
          return `${queryKey}${search ? "&" : "?"}cursor=${encodeURIComponent(
            JSON.stringify(previousPageData.after)
          )}`;
        },
        getFetcher(requestType),
        { fallbackData: initialData }
      );
```